# divs without height - how to make them stick and avoid whitespace

Tags: css, html, layout

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8hHA2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

i am trying to align these divs to stick , no luck .
how can we make it so that they stick to the previous div

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8hHA2/3/   .. Do you want it like this?

Comment: intresting , thanks will give it a try.

Comment: @appleBud  oh, i could do that but i dont want any whitespace between next div in height .. can it be done without any third party plugins.

Comment: That height depends on your content @SACHINHD . If one div is having content which is bigger than content of another div in size, then there will be height issues. If you want to remove that, you can probably give max-height to the div but in that case, you will have scroll bars.

Comment: @appleBud  that will be a neater design atleast .

Comment: @SACHINHD  Try this....  http://jsfiddle.net/8hHA2/9/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many `jQuery` libraries for that:

- [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) mentioned by *Era*
- [Gridster](http://gridster.net/)
- [Freewall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/)
- [Elastic Columns](https://github.com/johansatge/elastic-columns)
- [GridList](https://github.com/uberVU/grid)
- [Nested](http://suprb.com/apps/nested/)

Comment: There is examples provided, so `jQuery` knowledge is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them adjacent to each other, without any space between them, try this:

```
   .box{
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;  
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    min-height:200px;
    max-height:210px;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

However, in this design, you will have scroll bars in your divs. 
Hope it helps..  Or you can use the above mentioned library.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Create a container div with

```
font-size:0;
```

remove all margins from the box class css, and, rather than displaying it as inline floats, go for inline-block

```
.box{
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then, restate the font size for all child elements:

```
h3 {font-size:20px;}
p {font-size:15px;}
```

JsFiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/8hHA2/6/

Adding a margin-left: -1px; property to all boxes besides the first fixes the ugly double margin:

JsFiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/8hHA2/8/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.box {
        width: 150px;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px;
        margin: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        float: left;/**remove**/
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="boxdiv">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>TITLE</h3> 

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, iusto, voluptatibus autem non eaque veniam modi reprehenderit ducimus. Officiis, repellat.</p>

                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <h3>TITLE2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, saepe laborum natus laboriosam nesciunt aperiam.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>TITLE3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, recusandae, dolore molestias deserunt ex magnam esse a perferendis necessitatibus omnis. Dolore, eaque dolorem nesciunt fuga rerum dolores asperiores officia quidem!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>TITLE4</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, voluptatibus, veniam, eligendi magnam reiciendis numquam impedit tenetur accusantium voluptas laudantium praesentium consequatur recusandae deserunt delectus consequuntur esse commodi illum iure.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container {
font-size:0;
}


.box{
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 30px;

    overflow:hidden;

    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
font-size:20px;
}
p {
font-size:15px;
}
```